# Make child div width 100% of container with overflow-x using Flexbox

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a child div of a Flexbox container with overflowing-x content have 100% of the width WITH the overflow, but I can't figure out it, have made several searches and couldn't find a solution;

Can someone help me?

Fiddle: https://codepen.io/joaovtrc/pen/MWaaxKr

HTML:

```
<div class="test-container">

  <div class="test-item-overflow">
    overflowing contenttttttt
  </div>


  <div class="test-item-2"></div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.test-container {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  background: black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.test-item-overflow {
  width: fit-content;
  height: 55px;
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}

.test-item-2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 55px;
  background: blue;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

I want the 'test-item-2' (the one with the blue background) div to match the red one in width, but, keep in mind that the content on the redbox might not be exactly the same everytime, so no calc(100% + x) with fixed params...

Comment: `I want the 'test-item-2' (the one with the blue background) div to match the red one in width` did you mean height ?

Comment: @ZohirSalak No, I mean width, I want the blue box to match de width of the red one *with* the overflowing content still..

Comment: By default  a `<div>` is display block so it will match the width of it's parent, that requirement is implicit as long as you don't change the display property.

Comment: @ZohirSalak I removed the display: flex, and still the blueblox doesn't match the redbox width...

Comment: Because you have `width: fit-content;` which will also prevent the scrollbar you want, if you want blue to match the res remove `width: 1000px;` from the parent and add `display:inline-flex` this will also prevent scrollbars

Comment: @ZohirSalak but that's the point I **don't** want to remove the scrollbar, I just wanted the bluebox with the same width as the red one..

Comment: You can't have scrollbars if the parent width changes depending on the content thanks to  `width: fit-content;`

Answer (score 2):

As you have set the `width: fit-content;` for the overflow div, it makes the width uncontrollable as it grows with more content in that div. one solution might be to change the `width: 100%;` and add `overflow-x: scroll` to the class .test-item-overflow. (see the change in the below snippet)

However, if you want to keep the `width: fit-content;` for the red div and change the blue div's width along with the red one (depending on the content) you can add: `document.getElementsByClassName("test-item-2").style.width = document.getElementsByClassName("test-item-overflow").offsetWidth + "px"`. (in this case it's better to define id for the divs and use getElementById in the js code)

```css
.test-container {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  background: black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.test-item-overflow {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  height: 55px;
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}

.test-item-2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 55px;
  background: blue;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="test-container">

  <div class="test-item-overflow">
    aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  </div>


  <div class="test-item-2"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yeah, I was looking for a non javascript way to do this, but I guess that's the only way to make the bluebox match the red one... 

If someone knows how to do this using only CSS, please feel free to answer the question...

Answer (score 0):

So I really recommend you go ahead and add the following lines

```
Margin:0px;
```

This will take away all the space between your content and browser

```
Padding:0px;
```

This will take away all the space between your content and content border

```
Overflow:hidden;
```

Finally this should remove overflown content.

Hope that helped!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that's not quite what I was looking for. I want to keep the width of the redbox, and make the blue-box dynamically match the redbox width!

Comment: You mean overlap the boxes?

Answer (score 0):

Better to use `display:grid;` on `.test-container`. After if you dont want to have gap between to the 2 cells, this is due to `.test-container { height: 500px; }`.

### DEMO:

```css
html body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background: grey;
}

.test-container {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  background: black;
  /*display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;*/
  display:grid;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.test-item-overflow {
  width: 1500px;
  height: 55px;
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}

.test-item-2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 55px;
  background: blue;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="test-container">
  
  <div class="test-item-overflow">
   overflowing contenttttttt
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="test-item-2"></div>

</div>
```